# Detect if app starts after backup restore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, backup, restore

Is there a way in swift to detect if the app starts after restoring a backup?. Let's say make a backup on a device and restore it into another device.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a solution which seems to work after some testing. I tried several backup restores and it worked fine for me.

The first step would be to save the vendor identifier at the first run of the app:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "vendorID") == nil {
    if let vendorID = myDevice.identifierForVendor?.description {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(vendorID, forKey: "vendorID")
    }
}
```

The second step is to check if the saved vendor id matches the current device's vendor identifier.
Because the vendor id changes after a backup or restoring a backup to a device, I can do other action if the two vendor IDs don't match:

```
let savedVendorID = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "vendorID") as! String
if savedVendorID == myDevice.identifierForVendor?.description {
    //The app can start normally
} else {
    //Do action needed after backup restore
}
```

The vendor id changes under other conditions as well but for my app those changes doesn't matter.